# WebSocket connection to 'ws://46.229.214.83:8030/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, websocket, vds

Команда `new WebSocket("ws://46.229.214.83:8030");` выдаёт данную ошибку в консоли браузера, указанную в заголовке данного вопроса. `iptables -L` не выявляет ограничений для портов.

[image: iptables -L]

Смена номера порта не даёт положительного результата.

Данный сайт размещён на VDS. На виртуальном хостинге подобной ошибки не возникало. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Вы wss пробовали?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ поменял в протоколе на wss, всё равно выходит ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT